# MSB4057: The target "Release" does not exist in the project: in csproj in TeamCity

Tags: .net-core, teamcity

I've set up a build step using msbuild (Microsoft BuildTools 2019, ToolsVersion 16.0)

If I set build target to Release, I get the error in the title.
If I set build target to Debug, I get the equivalent error.

If I don't set a build target at all, I get:
`NETSDK1004: Assets file 'C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\b8126aa0ba178445\Test\Application\Matisa.Test.ApplicationEnums\obj\project.assets.json' not found`

I've tried switching to .NET CLI builder, but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you need to run `dotnet restore` in your pipeline somehow. You can try to add .NET CLI step with `restore` command to your build definition and place it before your msbuild step.

Comment: Thanks, I added Restore as a target and that (combined with correcting the silly bug in my answer) seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, silly me...

The target isn't `Debug` or `Release`, it's `Build/Restore` etc... Got mixed up.

Debug or Release goes in Parameters.